# Sum of two sets with combination

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

I'm a beginner in mathematics, so,
I may be confusing with the vectors...

Is there a name and definite operator for this operation ?

Two sets A and B :

$$A = \{ a_0, a_1 \} \\
B = \{ b_0, b_1, b_2 \} \\$$

$A [operator]  B = \{ a_0 + b_0, a_0 + b_1, a_0 + b_2, a_1 + b_0, a_1 + b_1, a_1 + b_2 \}$

Where [operator] is the operator which can done the result above.

Comment: You need define the dimensions of each vector and the subspace where it is. You are operating with vectors with a different number of dimensions, 2 and 3. You need a lot more definitions of the context.

Comment: Sometimes, one simply writes $A+B$ for this operation --- but one usually explains that that's what's meant.